# I want the random images in gallery how to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want a gallery somehow similar like the link below.

https://securemg.lincoln.com/musicselfie/gallery

The codes are too complex. so I dont know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide us your existing code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykarmacharya12/uk0758q5/

Thats what I have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're a beginner, anyway, is not complicated create random image, for example:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
img = new Array()
ran = Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
img[0] = 'immagine1.jpg';
img[1] = 'immagine2.jpg';
img[2] = 'immagine3.gif';
img[3] = 'immagine4.jpg';
document.write("<img src=\""+img[ran]+"\">");
// -->
</script>
```

I've a data structure to store the web address of the image, has been used a vector, in which I included a link to each "cell" of the vector. Then, using "ran" (random number between 1 and 4) do the choice of the image to display.
The method Math.floor (number) displays the nearest whole to `"number"`.

```
ES: Math.floor (12.5) becomes 12.
```

The random number is generated by switching to Math.floor with the `Math.random()` method (see Example [Math.random](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp)).
To get a random number between 0 and 4 multiply the random number returned by math.random () for 4.
However you could play around CSS and other tricks to javascript in order to build not only a good code to show the images but also to create a truly personalized slide as the site. You could also take the CSS site and adapt them to your code ...
Well with this consideration the example should be clear.